# Exclude certain dates/time in a average range between times that include dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get wait times that ignore certain dates/times.

The functioning formula is used to calculate wait time:

```
=SUM(IF(D3:D12-C3:C12>0,D3:D12-C3:C12))/COUNTA(D3:D12)
```

I'm using the if statement to exclude 0 or blank values.
The above formula does not exempt certain dates. Lets say I want to only include wait times from 16.09.23.

How would i go about to do this? I have attempted something like this:

```
=SUM(IFS(D3:D12-C3:C12>0,D3:D12-C3:C12, C3:C12,">=16.09.2023",C3-C12,"<17.09.2023"))/COUNTA(D3:D12)
```

Which gives me a #I/T error. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Screenshot of the Excel file:
[image: Excel file]

EDIT:
Since adding the great answer below. Changing dates to include wait times from other dates gives a wrong time. The expected answer is 00:10. But we get 00:01 instead.

The formula used is:
`=SUM(IF((D3:D12-C3:C12>0)*(C3:C12>=--"16.09.2023")*(C3:C12<--"17.09.2023"),D3:D12-C3:C12))/COUNTA(D3:D12)`
As this stand at the 16.09.2023 date this gives 00:08 as answer.
By removing the double hyphen at end time i get 00:10

```
=SUM(IF((D3:D12-C3:C12>0)*(C3:C12>=--"16.09.2023")*(C3:C12<"17.09.2023"),D3:D12-C3:C12))/COUNTA(D3:D12)
```

What needs to change so that it is adaptable to different dates aswell?
[Example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63u4I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use syntax like this:

```
=SUM(IF((D3:D12-C3:C12>0)*(C3:C12>=--"16.09.2023")*(C3:C12<--"17.09.2023"),D3:D12-C3:C12))/SUM((D3:D12-C3:C12>0)*(C3:C12>=--"16.09.2023")*(C3:C12<--"17.09.2023"))
```

`IFS` function is not suitable here as it checks for the first condition which is satisfied and you need all conditions to be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you! So if i understand correctly. IF with multiple parentheses works as multiple criterias then to check against?

Comment: You can use `IF` function with many logical criteria: multiplication means `AND`, addition means `OR`.

Comment: When i change dates the average times change. Expected result is 00:10 but i get 00:02. What in the syntax gives me this wrong result?

Comment: Show your formula and data. You may reduce number of rows if your data are so similar. By the way: do you use `Evaluate Formula` tool?

Comment: I edited the original question. I have never used Evaluate formula tool. I'll look it up and see if i can use it in my work.

Comment: The problem was in the denominator. You should count only rows which satisfy conditions and not all non-empty rows. Sorry that I didn't notice that before. I have edited my post.  
`--` is necessary to convert text into date (number). You cannot compare number to text because any text is greater than any number.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the good answers and explanation.